# How to create a function that resets all of the objects and vectors to null or initial values?

Tags: r, function, simulation, reset, assign

I am looking for a way to create [function](/questions/tagged/function) that resets all objects and vectors to their initial states. I am trying to create a [simulation](/questions/tagged/simulation) with iterations that reset certain objects and vectors at the end of a simulation.

I have tried creating a function called `reset` and then just calling it with `reset()` but it would never seemingly create the objects or at least they wouldn't show up in the environment for use.

Below are just the vectors and objects that I would like the reset to conduct.

```
reset = {
  iteration = (1:2)  ## Number of periods in the iteration of the loop.

  a = c() #lower bound of belief in xstar 
  b = c() #upper bound of belief in xstar

  #w1star = runif(1, min = 0, max = 3)
  #w2star = runif(1, min = 0, max = 3)

  D = 5 ## monetary value of harm from 

  maxw = 3
  minw = 0

  wbar = (maxw+minw)/2  ##average cost

  xstar = 1 - wbar/(2*D) #true legal threshold given that the court does not create multiple rules for each cost type, but instead makes one for all types, based on the average.
  xstar

  x1 = c()
  x2 = c()
  x3 = c()
  x  = c()

  w1 = runif(1,min = 0, max = 3) #cost of effort for person 1
  w2 = runif(1,min = 0, max = 3)
  w3 = runif(1,min = 0, max = 3)

  na = c()
  na1 = c()
  na2 = c()
  na3 = c()

  aggiter = c()
  aggnai = c()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it is better to achieve what you are doing in an alternative way.

What I would do is create a list called something like `state0` which holds the initial state, and then create a new object that changes the state as your simulation grows. For example:

```
# initialize the state
state0 <- list()
state0$iteration < 1:2
state0$a <- numeric()
state0$b <- numeric()
state0$D <- 5
state0$maxw <- 3
state0$minw <- 0
...

# assign initial state
state <- state0

# do the simulation
...simulation
...goes
...here

# reset
state <- state0
```

If you really want to do this with a function you have to assign variables in such a way that they are changed in global scope, not just locally within the function. In your specific case a special assignment `<<-` will work:

```
reset <- function() {
  iteration <<- 1:2
  a <<- numeric()
  b <<- numeric()
  D <<- 5
  maxw <<- 3
  minw <<- 3
  ...
}

reset()
```

Comment: The second option you suggested gives me the following error "Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'D'".... but I think the first one should work fine, thank you!